# re.findall Find numbers with dashes(-) and commas(,)

Tags: python

I have the value

```
x = '970.11 - 1,003.54'
```

I've tried many types of re.findall for example

```
re.findall('\+d',x)
['970', '11', '1', '003', '54']
```

although I would like for it to show

```
['970.11', '1,003.54]
```

Comment: will this help `'970.11 - 1,003.54'.split(' - ')` ?

Answer (score 3):

`\d` is only digits. It won't match other characters even if we think they are part of numbers. You need to do that manually with something like:

```
import re
x = '970.11 - 1,003.54'
re.findall('[\d\.,]+',x)  # match numbers .  or ,
```

result:

```
['970.11', '1,003.54']
```

This is a pretty forgiving regex — it will match a lot of things that probably aren't numbers (like `..,,4`). Numbers can be tricky to match with a regex if you want something that works in a general case (like `.45`, `11,000.2`, `22.`) etc. The more consistent your input, the easier it will be. And sometimes it's easier to match the nonmembers (like your `-`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it also works:

```
import re
re.findall('\d+\,?\d+\.*\d*',x)
```

Output:

```
['970.11', '1,003.54']
```

Here `,` is optional, if it is between the number it takes it otherwise it will not take it.
If you want `.` as optional then you can make it like this:

```
In [48]: x
Out[48]: '970.11 - 1,003.54 2345'

In [49]: re.findall('\d+\,?\d+\.?\d+',x)
Out[49]: ['970.11', '1,003.54', '2345']
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting this you might use grouping of regular expressions, using your example

```
x = '970.11 - 1,003.54'
y = re.findall('([0-9.,]+)([ -]+)([0-9.,]+)',x)
print(y[0]) #prints ('970.11', ' - ', '1,003.54')
z = [y[0][0],y[0][2]]
print(z) #prints ['970.11', '1,003.54']
```

Regular expression in this case consists of 3 groups: first and last match at least one of `0123456789.,` and middle at least one of `-` (space or dash)